# How to I hide or disable a choice in the context menu in javascript after clicking it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a context menu with 4 option, I want to hide or disable 1 option after clicking it.  these are my script fragments. After I click the save option, whenever I right click again on the div I want only the Move option available in the context menu. drag is the div class. is it possible?

```
var menu = [
            {'Move':function(menuItem,menuObject){
                    $(this).css({'backgroundColor':'red'});
                    return true; 
                } 
            },
            {'Save':function(menuItem,menuObject){
                    $(this).css({'backgroundColor':'blue'});
                    return true;
                }
            }
        ];

$(function() {
            $('.drag').contextMenu(menu,{
                showSpeed:500,
                hideSpeed:500,
                showTransition:'fadeIn',
                hideTransition:'fadeOut'
            });
        });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: oh! btw, Its just only 2 options now. Sorry for the typo. :D

Comment: please provide demo pages,screenshots or the rest of the code,I'm kind of confused as to what you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

First of all the class drag is the class of the parent element.
So you have to find the class of the "save" element. Lets suppose the class is .save, then on click remove it. This is done with this code:

```
$(".save").click(function{
 $(this).remove();
})
```

If you right click again, the element will be created again and the above function loses its purpose. So as I can see it, this is your problem.

But why do you need to hide the save button after something is "saved"? Maybe the user wants to save again.

It would be helpful if we could see a demo in order to understand the app you are trying to implement.

If you try to apply a rule only on changed (dragged) element you have to flag the changed ones in the class or in your db which holds the positions of the elements.
Then you can manipulate only the flagged (changed) through the jquery selector.

```
if ((.drag).hasClass('.changed')){
  $(".save").css({"visibility: visible"});
}
```

Dont forget to hide by default the element in css

```
.save{visibility: none}
```

Comment: ps post if you are using any jquery plugin

Comment: I am using jquery.contextmenu.js. I have a div which has a class name drag. and when that div is right clicked it shows the context menu which has 2 options, "Move and Save". I want to hide the Save option in the context menu after clicking the Save option so It cant be seen.